# How do I change the color of path in D3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am creating some paths ina  tree-graph in D3 and I'd like to change the color of the lines (paths), but I can't make my code work:

```
 // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
      link.enter().insert("svg:path", "g")
          .attr("class", "link")
          .attr("d", function(d) {
            var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
            return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
          })
        .transition()
          .duration(duration)
          .attr("d", diagonal);

      // Transition links to their new position.
      link.transition()
          .duration(duration)
          .attr("d", diagonal);

      // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
      link.exit().transition()
          .duration(duration)
          .attr("d", function(d) {
            var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
            return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
          })
          .remove();
```

I tried using the following to change and I've look-up up a few other solution, but I can't really understand what I need to select in my update selection to change it.

```
  link.selectAll("path")
      .attr("stroke", "#000000");
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: `link.style("stroke", "black")`

Comment: Thank you. Why don't I have to select path in this case?

Comment: The `link` selection contains the path elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm just starting with d3 myself, but I think you need to use link.style("stroke",#xxxxxx).

Answer (score 0):

An svg can change the color by using fill attribute (same is complex for path attribute even though its children of svg)

```
  svg
    .data([newValue])
    .transition()
    .duration(1500)
    .attr('fill', function(d) { return color(d); })
```

Working code for your reference:
https://jsfiddle.net/pjrc0yy3/1/